# External javascript call php for widget?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want that users can include my php file and load content from file in some class.

For example, let say that user have this file:
**user.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.php?width=100&height=100">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="my-class">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and i want from **myfile.php** in **.my-class** show some content:

```
<?php
$width = $_GET['width'];
$height = $_GET['height'];

echo "$('.my-class').load('load_content.php?width=$width&height=$height')";
?>
```

and in `load_content.php` something simple for now:

```
<?php 
echo $_GET['width'] + $_GET['height'];
?>
```

I can't find similar question anywhere, i tried something but only what i success is to document.write something on user.html from myfile.php, but when i tried load something or use innerHTML i get blank page.

Comment: since you're doing it as a script tag, that means your php script has to output **VALID** javascript code. that'd also mean you have to have jquery loaded already, since myfile is outputting a jquery call.

Comment: same is when i load jquery.

Comment: I did! When i add 
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do an ajax call using a `<script>` tag. Here's what you should rather do, since you have jquery included on your page already:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="my-class">
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get('load_content.php?width=100&height=100')
                .done(function(resp){
                    $('.my-class').html(resp);
                })
                .fail(function(){
                    $('.my-class').html('<h2>There was an error loading content</h2>');
                });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I solve it already, thank you for answer but this is not what i want.